# Get path for data storage

Tags: android

I need to create file in storage card from my Android program. I know I can create this file only in particular location like  `\Card\Android\data\my.application.package\`. How to get this directory exact location? Code below brings path `/data/my.application.package/Log` and `mkdirs()` does not creates directories.

```
        String path = "Log";

        File root = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                "my.application.package" + File.separator + path);

        boolean dirExists = true;

        if (!root.exists()) {
            dirExists = root.mkdirs();
        }
```

How to get the same application path on internal storage?

Comment: Have a look at getExternalFilesDIr(null); And getExternalFilesDirs() second item for removable micro SD card.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getFilesDir()` for getting app specific internal File path and `getExternalFilesDir()` for getting app specific external File path.

Note that on Android 4.3 (API level 18) or lower, your app need to request storage-related permissions to access app-specific directories within **external storage**.

For more information see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific